# Can't use Tkinter in Spyder 3.2.4

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I'm trying to do a really basic homework assignment, but can't get past the first step. I try to import Tkinter using "import tkinter" or "from tkinter import *" but neither are work. It says "label" and "button" and such are undefined. I'm sure its an easy fix but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, as I copied simple code from my textbook just to test it and it's still not working. Here's my code.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
label = Label(window, text = "This is a label.")
button = Button(window, text = "Press")
label.pack()
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

But I get the yellow warning signs on lines 1, 3, 4 and 5. 
Line 1: 'from tkinter import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
Lines 3-5: (blank) may be undefined, or defined from star inputs: tkinter

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure its simple. And I've searched the web but can't find a solution. I know very little about coding.

Answer (score 3):

The yellow triangles are warnings, not errors.  The Spyder IDE is checking that every callable has been defined.  In this case, it see that you are calling `Tk()`, `Label(...)`, and `Button(...)`, but they have not been defined or **explicitly** imported anywhere in your script.

Spyder knows nothing about what functions, classes, or modules are included in `tkinter`, so when you use the line

```
from tkinter import *
```

it has no idea what is included in the `*`, and it gives you a warning to that effect.

Doing `*` imports to the global is not a great practice anyhow, you don't know what is in your namespace.  Instead, explicitly import what you are using.  If you use the line:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
```

all of the warnings will vanish.

Comment: arguably even better, `import tkinter as tk` and then prefix the commands with `tk` (eg: `tk.Tk()`, tk.Button(...)`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I could do it like that:

```
from tkinter import Tk
raiz = Tk()
raiz.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3.7.1